# Netlogo: How to ask link-neighbor to do something

Tags: netlogo

I am simulating a classroom. In a classroom there are about 90 seats, 20 lights, 20 fans and 4 ACs. I create num-of-students where each student has an assigned random entry-time. When each student enters after a random time and sits on a seat the corresponding (in-radius)light or fan or ac turn on and a link is established between the the student and the in-radius appliance. Each appliance (e,g light, fan and AC) has their own wattage value. After all the students sits down the total energy consumption (in KWh) will be calculated for all the fans, lights and ACs.

How can I store the on-time of each appliance e.g (time minus entry-time), where time is the  total class time. So that afterwards I can sum all the on-time of each appliance(e.g fan) and multiply it with its watt value. This is the part of the code.

```
 globals[
  temp1 simulation-timer number-of-seats number-of-lights number- 
  of-fans number-of-acs ]
 breed [lights light] 
 breed [fans fan]
 breed [acs ac ]
 breed [students student ]

to setup
 ...
...
place-seats-students
place-lights
place-fans
place-acs
create-students-classroom
end

to create-students-classroom                                    
   create-students number-of-students [
   set entry-time random threshold + 1                          
   let stu-no sort-on [who] students                            
   foreach stu-no [x -> ask x [ show (word x " -> " entry-time ) 
   ] ]            
   ask students [
   set shape "person"
   set color 3
   ] ]
  end

to go
    set simulation-timer 0                              
    output-show (word "timer = "simulation-timer )     
    tick
    move-students
    while [simulation-timer < time ] [
    set simulation-timer simulation-timer + 1                       
    output-show (word "timer = "simulation-timer )
 end

 to move-students                                               
      let s sort [who] of seats
      let a first s
      let l length s
      while [ l > (number-of-seats - number-of-students )] [       
      set temp1 simulation-timer
      tick
      tick
      ask students [ if ( entry-time = temp1 ) [
      move-to seat a                                          
      set color red
      ask students
     [create-links-with lights in-radius 5
      create-links-with fans in-radius 5
      create-links-with acs in-radius 9 ]
      show (word "number of links is" count links)

    appliance-on
    store-on-time
    show (word temp1 "," l "," a)
    set s remove a s
    set a a + 1
    set l length s
     ]
   ]
    set simulation-timer simulation-timer + 1                       
    output-show (word "timer = "simulation-timer )]
   end

 to appliance-on

   ask students with [color = red ]
   [ask my-links
   [ask other-end [set color green] ] ]
  stop
end

 to store-on-time
  ask students [ 
    ask link-neighbor fan ifelse it is on [
    let on-time [ time - entry-time ]
    [do nothing]
 ask students [ 
    ask link-neighbor light ifelse it is on [
    let on-time [ time - entry-time ]
    [do nothing]
 end
```

How can I write the store-on-time procedure, so that later I will be able sum to all the on-times for all the appliance to calculate the KWh consumed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store something, then you need to create a variable for it. Since they might turn on, off, on etc, I would personally have two variables for each appliance (eg `lights-own` and `fans-own` etc). For lights, they could be named light-on-time, light-on-duration and similarly for others.

The way this works in code is add

```
set light-on-time ticks
```

whenever you turn the light on. And have

```
set light-on-duration light-on-duration + ticks - light-on-time + 1
```

whenever you turn the light off. The reporter `ticks` is just the current state of the clock.

Comment: ask students with [color = red]
  [ask my-links 
    [ if ( color = green )
      [set light-on-duration light-on-duration + ticks - light-on-time + 1 ]]]

but if I write this its giving an error saying you cant use light-on-duration in a link context.. Also the simulation-timer is actually the class time in minutes.

Comment: You can use your variable simulation-timer instead of `ticks` if you are doing something unusual with time, the principle is the same. What are your links doing? How does it work if a new student sits down near a light that is already on? You need to separate your lights turning on/off from the link creation. Then, when you turn the light on, you `ask` the light to `set` these variable values, not the link.

Comment: Yes I am also having problem in if a new student sits down near a light that is already on then that light will not add to the light-on-duration because it already has added previously. So should I do: ask students [ ask lights in-radius 4
    [ set color green ]]


other than :   ask students with [color = red ]                                   
  [ask my-links
    [ask other-end [set color green ] ] ]   ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the link? You can simply `ask` any light `in-radius` that is currently off to turn on and to also set the start time in the same code block.

Comment: Yes thanks I got that working but there are repetition in the light-on-duration as the light that is already on adds to the light-on-duration when another student sits next to it. What should I do in order to prevent the repetition?

Comment: You should only start the timer when the light turns on, and only add it to the duration when you turn it off (or the end of the simulation). The trick is to only turn on lights that are within radius if they are not already on. Please look at how to ask questions, you keep changing the question and trying to ask new questions in the comments.